# Best way to align controls in different sections of a form that has different controls and layout

Tags: forms, alignment, multi-column

I'm having a hard time designing a simple form to make it look neat. Below is the snapshot of my form which has different sections in the form.

Each section is having different combination of controls which could not fit in a universal column layout across the form. In this case how should we align the controls without wasting any real estate?

I've tried designing in 1 column/2 column/3 column layouts and I end up either misaligned controls in two different sections or I induce unnecessary space. Any inputs would be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a more condensed version of what you posted. I kept the read-only fields on a row separate from the inputs you can actually alter.
[image]